# I need to send mail for multiple textbox values

Tags: c#, .net, email

I need to send mail for more than 400 textbox values. A customer only enters 10 textbox values; how can I check and send the entered values to email?

Using the code below, I need to send only enter information to email. The blank text box is not needed to send. How can I check?

```
protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    mail.To = "mail@rediffmail.com";
    mail.Cc = "test@gmail.com";
    mail.From = Email.Value;

    mail.Body += "<table><tr><td>Name : " + Name.Value + " </td></tr>";

    mail.Body += " <tr><td>Mobile No</td><td>:</td><td> " + Mobile.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>State : " + states.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>Country : " + country.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>Requirements : " + Requirements.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>Message : " + Message.Value + "</td></tr><br><br>";



    mail.Body += "<table><tr><td>VOZARTHO (Capsule) : " + Textbox1.Value + " </td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<tr><td>VOZLAX (Tablets)</td> <td> :</td><td> " + Textbox2.Value + "</td> </tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>VOZZYME</td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox3.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>VOZ E TONE(syrup)</td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox4.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>VOZ COUGH plus</td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox5.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<table><tr><td>VOZITEX FORTE(capsule)</td><td>:</td> <td>" + Textbox6.Value + " </td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<tr><td>STHIRADI Kashayam</td> <td> :</td><td> " + Textbox7.Value + "</td> </tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>HAMSAPATHYADI Kashayam</td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox8.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>RASONADI Dravakam </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox9.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>NARASIMHA CHOORNAM</td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox10.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<table><tr><td>AJAMAMSARASAYANAM</td><td>:</td> <td>" + Textbox11.Value + " </td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<tr><td>AMRUTHAMALAKEE KASHAYAM</td> <td> :</td><td> " + Textbox12.Value + "</td> </tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>BACARE (POOKULA LEHYAM)</td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox13.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>DANTHADAVANA CHOORNAM</td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox14.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>NISAMALAKAM CHOORNAM</td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox15.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<table><tr><td>SNANA CHOORNAM</td><td>:</td> <td>" + Textbox16.Value + " </td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<tr><td>NEELEEBHRINGADI C/OIL</td> <td> :</td><td> " + Textbox22.Value + "</td> </tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>THENGIN POOKULA RASAYANAM</td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox23.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>DASAMOOLARASAYANAM</td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox24.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>DHANYAMLAM</td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox25.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<table><tr><td>DHANYAMLAM</td><td>:</td> <td>" + Textbox26.Value + " </td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<tr><td>HAMSAPATHYADI KASHAYAM</td> <td> :</td><td> " + Textbox27.Value + "</td> </tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>PIHEAL</td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox28.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>RASONADI DRAVAKAM</td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox29.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>STHIRADI KASHAYAM</td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox30.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>VYOSHAMRITHAM</td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox31.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<tr><td>ARAVINDASAVAM </td> <td> :</td><td> " + Textbox32.Value + "</td> </tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>BHRINGARAJASAVAM</td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox33.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>CHANDANASAVAM</td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox34.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>CHAVIKASAVAM</td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox35.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<table><tr><td>KANAKASAVAM(capsule)</td><td>:</td> <td>" + Textbox36.Value + " </td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<tr><td>KUMARYASAVAM</td> <td> :</td><td> " + Textbox37.Value + "</td> </tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>LODHRASAVAM</td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox38.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>LOHASAVAM </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox39.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>MADHOOKASAVAM </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox40.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<table><tr><td>NALIKERASAVAM</td><td>:</td> <td>" + Textbox41.Value + " </td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<tr><td>PIPPALYASAVAM</td> <td> :</td><td> " + Textbox42.Value + "</td> </tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>POOTHEEKARANJASAVAM</td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox43.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>POOTHEEVALKASAVAM</td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox44.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<table><tr><td>CHINCHADI THAILAM</td><td>:</td> <td>" + Textbox106.Value + " </td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<tr><td>DHANWANTHARAM THAILAM</td> <td> :</td><td> " + Textbox107.Value + "</td> </tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>DHANWANTHARAM THAILAM</td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox108.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>DHANWANTHARAM THAILAM</td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox109.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>HIMASAGARA THAILAM</td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox110.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<table><tr><td>KANJUNNYADI THAILAM</td><td>:</td> <td>" + Textbox111.Value + " </td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<tr><td>KARPASASTHYADI THAILAM</td> <td> :</td><td> " + Textbox112.Value + "</td> </tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>KARPASASTHYADI THAILAM</td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox113.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>KARPOORADI THAILAM</td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox114.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>KARPOORADI THAILAM</td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox115.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<table><tr><td>KARPOORADI THAILAM</td><td>:</td> <td>" + Textbox116.Value + " </td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<tr><td>KOTTAMCHUKKADI THAILAM</td> <td> :</td><td> " + Textbox117.Value + "</td> </tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>KOTTAMCHUKKADI THAILAM</td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox118.Value + "</td></tr>";





    mail.Body += " <tr><td>SHATPALAM GHRITHAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox241.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<tr><td>SUKUMARAM GHRITHAM     </td> <td> :</td><td> " + Textbox242.Value + "</td> </tr>";
    mail.Body += "<table><tr><td>KAISORAGULGULU GULIKA     </td><td>:</td> <td>" + Textbox256.Value + " </td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<tr><td>KAISORAGULGULU GULIKA     </td> <td> :</td><td> " + Textbox257.Value + "</td> </tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>KANCHANARAGULGULU GULIKA     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox258.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>KARUTHA VATTU     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox259.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>KASTHOORYADI GULIKA     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox260.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<table><tr><td>KOMPANCHADI GULIKA     </td><td>:</td> <td>" + Textbox261.Value + " </td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<tr><td>MANASAMITHRAM GULIKA     </td> <td> :</td><td> " + Textbox262.Value + "</td> </tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>MANDOORA VATAKAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox263.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>MUKKAMUKKUTAKADI GULIKA     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox264.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>NAVAYASAM GULIKA     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox265.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<table><tr><td>PONKARADI GULIKA     </td><td>:</td> <td>" + Textbox266.Value + " </td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<tr><td>SETHUBANDAM GULIKA     </td> <td> :</td><td> " + Textbox267.Value + "</td> </tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>SHADDHARANAM GULIKA     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox268.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>SHADDHARANAM GULIKA     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox269.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>SIVAGULIKA     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox270.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<table><tr><td>SOORYAPRABHA GULIKA     </td><td>:</td> <td>" + Textbox271.Value + " </td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<tr><td>SWASANANDAM GULIKA    </td> <td> :</td><td> " + Textbox272.Value + "</td> </tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>SWASANANDAM GULIKA     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox273.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>THRIPHALADI GULIKA     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox274.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>THRIPHALADI GULIKA      </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox275.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<table><tr><td>VAYU GULIKA     </td><td>:</td> <td>" + Textbox276.Value + " </td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<tr><td>VETTUMARAN GULIKA     </td> <td> :</td><td> " + Textbox277.Value + "</td> </tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>VETTUMARAN GULIKA     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox278.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>VILWADI GULIKA     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox279.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>VILWADI GULIKA     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox280.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<table><tr><td>YOGARAJAGULGULU GULIKA     </td><td>:</td> <td>" + Textbox281.Value + " </td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<tr><td>YOGARAJAGULGULU GULIKA     </td> <td> :</td><td> " + Textbox282.Value + "</td> </tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>ABAHAYAPIPPALIMOOLADI KASHAYAM    </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox283.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>AMRUTHOTHARAM KASHAYAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox284.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>ARAGWADHADI KASHAYAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox285.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<table><tr><td>ARAGWATHAMRUTHADHI KASHAYAM     </td><td>:</td> <td>" + Textbox286.Value + " </td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<tr><td>ASHTAVARGAM KASHAYAM     </td> <td> :</td><td> " + Textbox287.Value + "</td> </tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>BALAJEERAKADI KASHAYAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox288.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>BALAKULATHADI KASHAYAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox289.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>BHADRADARVADI KASHAYAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox290.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>BHRUHATHYADI KASHAYAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox291.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<tr><td>CHIRUVILWADI KASHAYAM     </td> <td> :</td><td> " + Textbox292.Value + "</td> </tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>CHITRAKADI KASHAYAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox293.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>DASAMOOLAKADUTHRAYAM KASHAYAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox294.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>DASAMOOLAM KASHAYAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox295.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<table><tr><td>DASAMOOLARASNADI KASHAYAM     </td><td>:</td> <td>" + Textbox296.Value + " </td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<tr><td>DHANADANAYANADI KASHAYAM     </td> <td> :</td><td> " + Textbox297.Value + "</td> </tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>DHANWANTHARAM IRATTY KASHAYAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox298.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>DHANWANTHARAM KASHAYAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox299.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>DRAKSHADI KASHAYAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox300.Value + "</td></tr>";



    mail.Body += "<table><tr><td>NASIKACHOORNAM </td><td>:</td> <td>" + Textbox301.Value + " </td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<tr><td>DUSPARSAKADI KASHAYAM    </td> <td> :</td><td> " + Textbox302.Value + "</td> </tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>ELAKANADI KASHAYAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox303.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>GANDHARAVAHASTHADI KASHAYAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox304.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>GULGULUTHIKTHAKAM KASHAYAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox305.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<table><tr><td>GULOOCHYADI KASHAYAM     </td><td>:</td> <td>" + Textbox306.Value + " </td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<tr><td>INDUKANTHAM KASHAYAM    </td> <td> :</td><td> " + Textbox307.Value + "</td> </tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>KAIDARYADI KASHAYAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox308.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>KALASAKADI KASHAYAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox309.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>KANASATHAHAWATHI KASHAYAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox310.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<table><tr><td>KATHAKAKHADIRATHI KASHAYAM     </td><td>:</td> <td>" + Textbox311.Value + " </td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<tr><td>KOKILAKSHADI KASHAYAM     </td> <td> :</td><td> " + Textbox312.Value + "</td> </tr>";
    mail.Body += "<table><tr><td>MAHATHIKTHAKAM KASHAYAM     </td><td>:</td> <td>" + Textbox316.Value + " </td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<tr><td>MANJISHTADI KASHAYAM     </td> <td> :</td><td> " + Textbox317.Value + "</td> </tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>MUSALEEKHADIRADI KASHAYAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox318.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>NAYOPAYAM KASHAYAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox319.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>NIMBADI KASHAYAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox320.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<table><tr><td>NISAKHATHAKADI KASHAYAM     </td><td>:</td> <td>" + Textbox321.Value + " </td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<tr><td>PADATHI KASHAYAM     </td> <td> :</td><td> " + Textbox322.Value + "</td> </tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>PATHYAPUNARNNAVADI KASHAYAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox323.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>PATHYASHATGAM KASHAYAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox324.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>PATOLAKADUROHINYADI KASHAYAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox325.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<table><tr><td>PATOLAMOOLADI KASHAYAM     </td><td>:</td> <td>" + Textbox326.Value + " </td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<tr><td>PRASARINYADI KASHAYAM     </td> <td> :</td><td> " + Textbox327.Value + "</td> </tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>PUNARNAVADI KASHAYAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox328.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>RASNADI KASHAYAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox329.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>RASNADI SPECIAL KASHAYAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox330.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<table><tr><td>RASNASAPTHAKAM KASHAYAM     </td><td>:</td> <td>" + Textbox331.Value + " </td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<tr><td>RASNASUNDYADI KASHAYAM     </td> <td> :</td><td> " + Textbox332.Value + "</td> </tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>RASNEIRANDADI KASHAYAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox333.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>RASONADI KASHAYAM    </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox334.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>SAHACHARADI KASHAYAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox335.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<table><tr><td>SAPTHASARAM KASHAYAM     </td><td>:</td> <td>" + Textbox336.Value + " </td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<tr><td>SATHAVAREECHINNURUHATHI KASHAYAM     </td> <td> :</td><td> " + Textbox337.Value + "</td> </tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>SATHAVAREEGOPAKANYADI KASHAYAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox338.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>SUKUMARAM KASHAYAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox339.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>THIKTHAKAM KASHAYAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox340.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>THRIJATHADI KASHAYAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox341.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<tr><td>VARANADI KASHAYAM     </td> <td> :</td><td> " + Textbox342.Value + "</td> </tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>VARASANADI KASHAYAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox343.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>VASAGULUCHYADI KASHAYAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox344.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>VIDARYADI KASHAYAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox345.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<table><tr><td>VILANGAKRISHNADI KASHAYAM     </td><td>:</td> <td>" + Textbox346.Value + " </td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<tr><td>VYAGHRADI KASHAYAM     </td> <td> :</td><td> " + Textbox347.Value + "</td> </tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>VYOSHADI KASHAYAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox348.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>HAMSAPATHYADI KASHAYAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox349.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>AGASTHYA RASAYANAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox350.Value + "</td></tr>";



    mail.Body += "<table><tr><td>AGASTHYA RASAYANAM     </td><td>:</td> <td>" + Textbox351.Value + " </td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<tr><td>AGASTHYA RASAYANAM     </td> <td> :</td><td> " + Textbox352.Value + "</td> </tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>ASWAGANDHADI LEHYAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox353.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>BAHUSALAGULAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox354.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>BAHUSALAGULAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox355.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<table><tr><td>BRAHMA RASAYANAM     </td><td>:</td> <td>" + Textbox356.Value + " </td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<tr><td>CHINCHADI LEHYAM     </td> <td> :</td><td> " + Textbox357.Value + "</td> </tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>DASAMOOLA RASAYANAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox358.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>DASAMOOLA RASAYANAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox359.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>DASAMOOLAHAREETHAKI LEHYAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox360.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<table><tr><td>DASAMOOLAHAREETHAKI LEHYAM     </td><td>:</td> <td>" + Textbox361.Value + " </td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<tr><td>DRAKSHADI LEHYAM     </td> <td> :</td><td> " + Textbox362.Value + "</td> </tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>HRIDYAVIRECHANAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox363.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>HRIDYAVIRECHANAM    </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox364.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>KALYANAGULAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox365.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<table><tr><td>KALYANAGULAM     </td><td>:</td> <td>" + Textbox366.Value + " </td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<tr><td>KOOSHMANDARASAYANAM     </td> <td> :</td><td> " + Textbox367.Value + "</td> </tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>KOOSHMANDARASAYANAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox368.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>MADHUSNUHI RASAYANAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox369.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>MANIBHADRAM LEHYAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox370.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<table><tr><td>MANIBHADRAM LEHYAM     </td><td>:</td> <td>" + Textbox371.Value + " </td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<tr><td>NAYOPAYAM LEHYAM     </td> <td> :</td><td> " + Textbox372.Value + "</td> </tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>PULIMKUZHAMBU LEHYAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox373.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>SATHAVAREEGULAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox374.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>SATHAVAREEGULAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox375.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<table><tr><td>SUKUMARA RASAYANAM     </td><td>:</td> <td>" + Textbox376.Value + " </td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<tr><td>THALEESAPATHRADI VADAKAM     </td> <td> :</td><td> " + Textbox377.Value + "</td> </tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>VIDARYADI LEHYAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox378.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>VIDARYADI LEHYAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox379.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>VILWADI LEHYAM     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox380.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<table><tr><td>VILWADI LEHYAM     </td><td>:</td> <td>" + Textbox381.Value + " </td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<tr><td>VYOSHADI VATAKAM     </td> <td> :</td><td> " + Textbox382.Value + "</td> </tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>DHANWANTHARAM KUZHAMBU     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox383.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>DHANWANTHARAM KUZHAMBU     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox384.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>DHANWANTHARAM KUZHAMBU     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox385.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<table><tr><td>KARPASASTHYADI KUZHAMBU     </td><td>:</td> <td>" + Textbox386.Value + " </td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<tr><td>KARPASASTHYADI KUZHAMBU     </td> <td> :</td><td> " + Textbox387.Value + "</td> </tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>KARPASASTHYADI KUZHAMBU     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox388.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>KOTTAMCHUKKADI KUZHAMBU     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox389.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>KOTTAMCHUKKADI KUZHAMBU     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox390.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>KOTTAMCHUKKADI KUZHAMBU     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox391.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<tr><td>NALPAMARADI KUZHAMBU    </td> <td> :</td><td> " + Textbox392.Value + "</td> </tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>PRABANJANAM KUZHAMBU     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox393.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>PRABANJANAM KUZHAMBU     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox394.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>PRABANJANAM KUZHAMBU     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox395.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<table><tr><td>SAHACHARADI KUZHAMBU     </td><td>:</td> <td>" + Textbox396.Value + " </td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<tr><td>SAHACHARADI KUZHAMBU     </td> <td> :</td><td> " + Textbox397.Value + "</td> </tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>SAHACHARADI KUZHAMBU     </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox398.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>VOZARTHO CAPSULES </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox399.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>VOZARTHO CAPSULES </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox400.Value + "</td></tr>";



    mail.Body += "<table><tr><td>VOZCUF PLUS SYRUP </td><td>:</td> <td>" + Textbox401.Value + " </td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<tr><td>VOZE TONE SYRUP </td> <td> :</td><td> " + Textbox402.Value + "</td> </tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>VOZITEX FORT CAPSULE </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox403.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>VOZLAX CAPSULES </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox404.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>VOZZYME SYRUP </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox405.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<table><tr><td>AJAMAMSARASAYANAM </td><td>:</td> <td>" + Textbox406.Value + " </td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<tr><td>AMRUTHAMALAKEE KASHAYAM </td> <td> :</td><td> " + Textbox407.Value + "</td> </tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>BACARE (POOKULA LEHYAM) </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox408.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>DANTHADAVANA CHOORNAM </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox409.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>NISAMALAKAM CHOORNAM  </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox410.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<table><tr><td>SNANA CHOORNAM </td><td>:</td> <td>" + Textbox411.Value + " </td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<tr><td>ELANEER KUZHAMBU </td> <td> :</td><td> " + Textbox412.Value + "</td> </tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>CHYAVANAPRASAM </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox413.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>DHATHRYARISHTAM </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox414.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>DMJ </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox415.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<table><tr><td>NEELEEBHRINGADI C/OIL </td><td>:</td> <td>" + Textbox416.Value + " </td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<tr><td>NEELEEBHRINGADI C/OIL </td> <td> :</td><td> " + Textbox417.Value + "</td> </tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>SARASWATHARISHTAM(GOLD) </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox418.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>THENGIN POOKULA RASAYANAM </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox419.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>DASAMOOLARASAYANAM </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox420.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<table><tr><td>DHANYAMLAM </td><td>:</td> <td>" + Textbox421.Value + " </td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<tr><td>DHANYAMLAM    </td> <td> :</td><td> " + Textbox422.Value + "</td> </tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>HAMSAPATHYADI KASHAYAM </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox423.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>NARASIMHACHOORNAM </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox424.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>PIHEAL </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox425.Value + "</td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<table><tr><td>RASONADI DRAVAKAM </td><td>:</td> <td>" + Textbox426.Value + " </td></tr>";
    mail.Body += "<tr><td>STHIRADI KASHAYAM </td> <td> :</td><td> " + Textbox427.Value + "</td> </tr>";
    mail.Body += " <tr><td>VYOSHAMRITHAM </td><td>:</td><td> " + Textbox428.Value + "</td></tr>";


    // email subject
    mail.Subject = "Order / Buy Submission from www.domain.com ";

    mail.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html;
    SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net";

    try
    {
        newval = true;
        SmtpMail.Send(mail);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        newval = false;
    }
    if (newval == true)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Order_reply.aspx");
    }
    else if (newval == false)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Order_reply.aspx");
    }

}



}
```

Comment: Welcome to [SO]. You have not said what language and software you are using. Please used the [edit] button to add the missing information. You should also read [mcve].

Comment: @Brian Tompsett - this is obviously C#.net ..

Comment: @polisha989 Thanks. You could have edited that in yourself! [SO] is a community edited site in the wiki style.

Answer (score 1):

iterate through the Text boxes in your form
you can do something like:

```
        string body= string.Empty;

        foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
        {
            if (control is TextBox)
            { 
                //get text from textbox
                string text_content = control.Value;

                //make sure its not empty
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text_content))
                {
                    body +=  /*all your mumbo jumbo HTML table data  + */ text_content;
                }

            }
        }

        mail.Body = body;
```